# Using LocalStorage with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

From what I am experiencing so far, it doesn't seem like ReactJS updates with the state of localStorage. My code below.

```
var Frr = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function(){
return { lights: localStorage.getItem('state')}
},

switchoff: function(){
this.setState({lights: localStorage.setItem('state', 'off')}); 
},

switchon:function(){
this.setState({lights: localStorage.setItem('state', 'on')}); 
},

render:function(){
if (this.state.lights === 'on'){ return (
<div>
<p>The lights are ON</p>
<input type="submit" value="Switch" onClick={this.switchoff}/>
</div>
);}

if ( (this.state.lights === 'off')|| (!this.state.lights) ){ return (
<div>
<p>The lights are OFF</p>
<input type="submit" value="Switch" onClick={this.switchon}/>
</div>
);}


}
});
```

Simple application. If the state of localstorage is off or empty, then render the view with the ON button. If localstorage is on, then render the view with the OFF button.

I want to be able to set this render based on the state of localStorage. I have tried doing the same thing using basic booleans, and it works as expected. However, when using localStorage, something doesn't appear to work.

I wouldn't be surprised if my logic is simply off.

EDIT: To explain, the button and the view don't act as they should. When the lights are off and there is nothing in Storage, the button adds ON to localStorage, but does not change the view. If I refresh the page, the page renders ON, and when I click on it the button works by turning it OFF. But it only works once, which leads me to believe there may be a problem with the OFF switch.

Comment: *something doesn't appear to work* -- **what** doesn't appear to work, and in what way?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The `.setItem()` local storage function returns `undefined`. You need to perform the local storage update and then return the new state object:

```
switchoff: function(){
    localStorage.setItem('state', 'off');
    this.setState({lights: 'off'}); 
},
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is just another Example:

```
import React from 'react'
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var storedClicks = 0;

    if (localStorage.getItem('clicks')) {
      storedClicks = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('clicks'));
    }

    this.state = {
      clicks: storedClicks,
    };
    this.click = this.click.bind(this);
  }

  click() {
    var newclick = this.state.clicks + 1;
    this.setState({clicks: newclick});
    // Set it
    localStorage.setItem('clicks', newclick);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Click the button a few times and refresh page</h2>
        <button onClick={this.click}>Click me</button> Counter {this.state.clicks}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 5):

These 4 methods u can use.

```
// setter
localStorage.setItem('myData', data);
// getter
localStorage.getItem('myData');
// remove
localStorage.removeItem('myData');
// remove all
localStorage.clear();
```

Comment: In React, I have this exact code and after running it's still empty: `localStorage.setItem("test", "test");`

Comment: I needed to add "window." to the beginning of each of the methods in order for them to work.

Answer (score 2):

Use please [reactjs-localstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactjs-localstorage)

```
import {reactLocalStorage} from 'reactjs-localstorage';

reactLocalStorage.set('var', true);
reactLocalStorage.get('var', true);
reactLocalStorage.setObject('var', {'test': 'test'});
reactLocalStorage.getObject('var');
```

Comment: no need to use third party lib, since there's a default one

Answer (score 2):

I have written a post regarding this question with some extra information regarding when you should use localStorage:

https://levbuchel.com/react-localstorage/

---

Original answer:

Your data is determined and saved by pairs of key and value.

Here is an example of how we can add, get and remove such values:

```
// Add items
localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
localStorage.setItem("zoom", "5");
localStorage.setItem("font", "18");

// Get an item
var userTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");

// Remove an item
localStorage.removeItem("theme");
localStorage.removeItem("font");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [use-local-storage-state](https://github.com/astoilkov/use-local-storage-state). Handling all edge-cases when dealing with localStorage is actually hard.

I created the library one year ago and have been maintaining it for the entire time.

Answer (score 0):

React/Typescript/localStorage

You can create a hook to make it more fun to work with localStorage.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const useLocalStorage = (storageKey: string, fallbackState: any) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<any>(fallbackState);
  const [error, setError] = useState<any>();

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const getItemValue = JSON.parse(
        localStorage.getItem(storageKey) as string
      );
      if (getItemValue) {
        setValue(currentValue);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setError(e);
    }
  }, [storageKey]);

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      localStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(value));
    } catch (e) {
      setError(e);
    }
  }, [fallbackState, storageKey, value]);

  return { value, setValue, error };
};
```

Usage

```
const defaultValue = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  location: 'New York',
}

const {
  value
  setValue
  error,
} = useLocalStorage('local-storage-key', defaultValue);
```

`value` contains the current localStorage value for key `local-storage-key`.

You can use `setValue` to set a new value

And `error` returns any error that was returned from the `catch` in the hook.

Answer (score -1):

```
const { data } = response;

const userData = data.user;
// Token Save to local Storage

const access = JSON.stringify(data.tokens);
const refresh = JSON.stringify(data.tokens);

localStorage.setItem('accessToken', access);
localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', refresh);
```