# how to save react js state into localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, local-storage

I have no idea How to store the react js state into localstorage.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css';
import { auth,createUserProfileDocument } from './firebase/firebase.utils'
import { TodoForm } from './components/TodoForm/TodoForm.component'
import {TodoList} from './components/TodoList/TodoList.component'
import {Footer} from './components/footer/footer.component'
import Header from '../src/components/header/header.component'
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'

import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {setCurrentUser} from './redux/user/user.actions'

export class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.input=React.createRef()
    this.state = {
        todos:[
         {id:0, content:'Welcome Sir!',isCompleted:null},
        ]


    }
  }

  todoDelete = (id) =>{
    const todos = this.state.todos.filter(todo => {
      return todo.id !== id 
    })
    this.setState({
      todos
    })
  }
   toDoComplete = (id,isCompleted) =>{
     console.log(isCompleted)
     var todos = [...this.state.todos];
     var index = todos.findIndex(obj => obj.id === id);
     todos[index].isCompleted = !isCompleted;
     this.setState({todos});
     console.log(isCompleted)
      }

  addTODO = (todo) =>{
         todo.id = Math.random()
         todo.isCompleted = true
         let todos = [...this.state.todos, todo]
         this.setState({
           todos
         })
  }


 unsubscribeFromAuth = null;

 componentDidMount() {
  const { setCurrentUser } = this.props;

  this.unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async userAuth => {
    if (userAuth) {
      const userRef = await createUserProfileDocument(userAuth);

      userRef.onSnapshot(snapShot => {
        setCurrentUser({
          id: snapShot.id,
          ...snapShot.data()
        });
      });
    }

    setCurrentUser(userAuth);
  });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.unsubscribeFromAuth();
}

  render() {
    return (

      <div className='App'>
            <Header />
            <TodoForm addTODO={this.addTODO} />
            <TodoList 
              todos={this.state.todos} 
              todoDelete={ this.todoDelete} 
              toDoComplete={ this.toDoComplete}
           />
            <Footer/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ user }) => ({
  currentUser: user.currentUser
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setCurrentUser: user => dispatch(setCurrentUser(user))
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

in my input Form

```
import './TodoForm.style.css'
export class TodoForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
             content : ''
        }
    }
    handleChange = (e) =>{
        this.setState({
            content: e.target.value
        })
    }
    handleSubmit =(e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.addTODO(this.state);
        this.setState({
            content: ''
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='inputTask'>
                <form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit}>

                    <input 
                    className="textBox" 
                    type='text' 
                    onChange={ this.handleChange} 
                    value={this.state.content}
                    placeholder='what you want to do ...'
                    />
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TodoForm
```

I have no idea How to store the react js state into localstorage.
i searched on internet but unable to find the exact solution all the codes that i think is necessary post.

Comment: Which data you want to store into localStorage ?

Comment: @RiponUddin todos object which recieved from user

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using LocalStorage with React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423108/using-localstorage-with-react)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reactLocalStorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactjs-localstorage) to save any data in local storage

```
import {reactLocalStorage} from 'reactjs-localstorage';

reactLocalStorage.set('var', true);
reactLocalStorage.get('var', true);
reactLocalStorage.setObject('var', {'test': 'test'});
reactLocalStorage.getObject('var');
reactLocalStorage.remove('var');
reactLocalStorage.clear();
```

Comment: where to write this

Answer (score 1):

Read out the `localStorage` item in the `componentDidMount` callback. Simply read the item you want to get, check if it exists and parse it to a usable object, array or datatype that need. Then set the state with the results gotten from the storage.

And to store it, simply handle it in an event handler or helper method to update both the state and the `localStorage` item.

```
class ExampleComponent extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      something: {
        foo: 'bar'
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const storedState = localStorage.getItem('state');
    if (storedState !== null) {
      const parsedState = JSON.parse(storedState);
      this.setState({ something: parsedState });
    }
  }

  clickHandler = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    const stringifiedValue = JSON.stringify(value);
    localStorage.setItem('state', stringifiedValue);
    this.setState({ something: value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={clickHandler} value={this.state.something}>Click me</button>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: @DeepakBhamla Can you create a sandbox? We can debug.

Answer (score 0):

Set data in localStorage

key-value pair :

```
localStorage.setItem('key_name',"value");
```

object

```
localStorage.setItem('key_name', JSON.stringify(object));
```

Remove data from localStorage

```
localStorage.removeItem('key_name');
```

Get data from localStorage

```
 let data = localStorage.getItem('key_name');
```

object :

```
let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key_name'));
```

clear localStorage (delete all data)

```
localStorage.clear();
```